# SageMaker Studio Image - pip not found and no python 3 in terminal for Python 3 notebook instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

Launched Data Science Python 3 instance in the SageMaker Studio.

[image]
Launched a terminal from the Notebook menu "Launch terminal in current SageMaker image".

[image]

Tried to run pip but it says not found. Do I need to install pip by myself?

```
root@datascience-1-0-ml-t3-medium-1abf3407f667f989be9d86559395:~/# pip
bash: pip: command not found
```

Alto there is no Python3 available apparently from within the terminal.

```
root@datascience-1-0-ml-t3-medium-1abf3407f667f989be9d86559395:~# python3 
bash: python3: command not found

root@datascience-1-0-ml-t3-medium-1abf3407f667f989be9d86559395:~# python --version
Python 2.7.16

root@datascience-1-0-ml-t3-medium-1abf3407f667f989be9d86559395:/usr/bin# ls -lrt | grep python
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        29 Mar  4  2019 pyversions -> ../share/python/pyversions.py
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root         9 Mar  4  2019 python2 -> python2.7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root         7 Mar  4  2019 python -> python2
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      1056 Mar  4  2019 dh_python2
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   3689352 Oct 10  2019 python2.7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        23 Oct 10  2019 pdb2.7 -> ../lib/python2.7/pdb.py
```

However, the notebook says it is Python3.

```
from platform import python_version
print(python_version())
---
3.7.10
```

[image]

And can run pip in the cell.

[image]

Appreciate any explanation what is going on.

Answer (score 3):

SageMaker Studio image terminals use conda for package management. The data science notebook uses the `base` environment. You can use pip once you switch to base (also note that the python version is 3.7).

```
root@datascience-1-0-ml-t3-medium-xx:~# conda env list
# conda environments:
#
base                  *  /opt/conda

root@datascience-1-0-ml-t3-medium-xx:~# conda activate base

(base) root@datascience-1-0-ml-t3-medium-xx:~# pip show pip
Name: pip
Version: 21.3.1
Summary: The PyPA recommended tool for installing Python packages.
Home-page: https://pip.pypa.io/
Author: The pip developers
Author-email: distutils-sig@python.org
License: MIT
Location: /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages
Requires: 
Required-by: 

(base) root@datascience-1-0-ml-t3-medium-1abf3407f667f989be9d86559395:~# python --version
Python 3.7.10
```

I work at AWS and my opinions are my own.

Answer (score 0):

Was stuck in the same issue in Sagemaker notebook instance. Followed the guide [here](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/sagemaker/latest/dg/studio-notebooks-add-external.html) and resolved it by running:

```
%pip install matplotlib
```

Attaching the screenshot for your reference:

[image]